# how to refresh the page with original URL when URL has been changed via history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, php

I have used history.pushState() and now if the user refreshes the page then it is refreshing current URL which is not an original URL.

I tried detecting refresh page with a cookie, hidden filed but it is not working.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.cookie="PR=0";     

var read_cookies = document.cookie;


var s = read_cookies;
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(';'));

  if( s.includes("1"))
{
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";


}
else{

    document.cookie="PR=1";     
}

  loadURL();

};


function loadURL()
  {
  document.cookie="PR=1";       

  document.getElementById("visited").value="1";


  var str="abc/b cd";
  str=str.replace(/ /g, "-");
  history.pushState({},"",str);
  }
```

when user is refreshing the page I need original URL on that time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. But you need control over the pushed url.

```
// this goes to your 'original' url
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('lastPage', window.location.href)
}

// page with your pushed url
if (sessionStorage.getItem('lastPage') === 'PAGE_YOU_DONT_WANT_TO_BE_REACHABLE_DIRECTLY') {
    window.location = 'PAGE_YOU_WANT'
}
```

I'm interested what the use case for this is. As far as my knowledge goes you can't suppress the refresh event completely.